# Como Selecionar a segunda linha de um texto em textbox e muda la para a primeira linha

Tags: vb.net

Estou a tentar fazer um editor de texto , mas estou a encontrar dificuldades em encontrar uma solução para seleccionar a segunda linha de um texto em textbox multiplas linhas e quero mudar a segunda linha pela pimeira.
Ja tentei pesquisar sobre isso e nao encontro nenhum exemplo.

Esta foi a tentativa que fiz mas sem resultado esperado.

```
Dim CRPos As Integer

    CRPos = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(Chr(10))

    If CRPos > -1 Then

        TextBox1.Select(1, CRPos)
        TextBox1.SelectionLength = CRPos
        TextBox1.SelectedText = ""

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O controle `TextBox` possui a propriedade `Lines`, que retorna um array de `String` com cada linha do texto contido no controle.

Além disso o controle também expõe os métodos `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine()` e `GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()`, que retornam o índice do primeiro caractere de determinada linha ou da linha corrente (a numeração das linhas começa em zero).

Então, o código para selecionar a segunda linha de um `TextBox` com propriedade `Multiline` definida como *True* poderia ser assim:

```
Private SelecionarLinha2()

   ' Primeiro é necessário verificar se há pelo menos duas linhas.
   If TextBox1.Lines.Count > 1 Then
      ' Seleciona trecho do texto do controle começando no
      ' primeiro caractere da segunda linha (lineNumber=1).
      TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(1), TextBox1.Lines(1).Length)
      ' Se o foco não for enviado para o controle TextBox, a seleção não aparecerá.
      TextBox1.Focus()
   End If

End Sub
```

E o código para trocar a segunda linha pela primeira:

```
Private Sub TrocarLinha2PorLinha1()

   ' Primeiro é necessário verificar se há pelo menos duas linhas.
   If TextBox1.Lines.Count > 1 Then
      Dim troca As String
      ' Quando a propriedade Lines é criada automaticamente a partir
      ' do texto digitado no controle, o array retornado por ela é
      ' apenas uma cópia somente leitura das linhas do controle,
      ' então, o texto não pode ser alterado diretamente na propriedade,
      ' por isso é necessário usar um array temporário.
      Dim linhas() As String = TextBox1.Lines

      ' Troca a segunda linha pela primeira linha.    
      troca = linhas(1)
      linhas(1) = linhas(0)
      linhas(0) = troca

      ' Devolve o array modificado para o controle.    
      TextBox1.Lines = linhas
   End If

End Sub
```

Também daria para fazer as mesmas coisas usando o "jeito antigo".
Aqui o código para selecionar a segunda linha:

```
Private SelecionarLinha2_JeitoAntigo()

   Dim posQuebraDeLinha As Integer = -1
   Dim firstCharIndex As Integer = -1
   Dim lineTwoLength As Integer = 0

   ' Busca pela quebra de linha da primeira linha.
   posQuebraDeLinha = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(vbCrLf)
   If posQuebraDeLinha < 0 Then Return
   ' Índice do primeiro caractere da segunda linha.
   firstCharIndex = posQuebraDeLinha + 2   '2 = Len(vbCrLf)

   ' Busca pela quebra de linha da segunda linha.
   posQuebraDeLinha = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(vbCrLf, firstCharIndex)
   If posQuebraDeLinha < 0 Then posQuebraDeLinha = TextBox1.TextLength

   ' Calcula o comprimento do texto na segunda linha.
   lineTwoLength = posQuebraDeLinha - firstCharIndex

   TextBox1.Select(firstCharIndex, lineTwoLength)
   TextBox1.Focus()

End Sub
```

E o código para trocar a segunda linha pela primeira, do "jeito antigo":

```
Private Sub TrocarLinha2PorLinha1_JeitoAntigo()

   Dim troca As String
   ' Divide o texto usando a sequência de CarriageReturn (13) + LineFeed (10)
   ' como separador, resultando em um array em que cada item é uma linha.
   Dim linhas() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf)

   If linhas.Count > 1 Then
      troca = linhas(1)
      linhas(1) = linhas(0)
      linhas(0) = troca

      ' Junta de volta as linhas do array, usando de novo a sequência
      ' de CarriageReturn (13) + LineFeed (10) como separador.
      TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, linhas)
   End If

End Sub
```